# android location services and activity lifecycle

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-lifecycle

I have an Activity that implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks.  When the launcher icon is pressed, the location is immediately calculated because according to my logs onConnected runs before onCreate.  Is the following possible?

After initially installing my app and opening it the location is calculated.  Further calculations require the user to press the refresh button.

I do this because I use the location to immediately open a DialogFragment with data pertaining to that location.  Upon selecting something in the dialog, the user sees results in the Activity that dialog was a part of.

So if the user stays in the same vicinity, I don't want him to see a dialog pop up every time he opens the app, it should just show the Activity that was populated before.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
    Log.d("MY_DEBUG", "In SelectActivity's onConnected.  Successfully connected to loc services");
    mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    // Display the connection status
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    showListingDialog();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think it's very possible to do what you want to do. It would be helpful for you to post the relevant code.

Comment: please see original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a boolean flag on your class like this:

```
private boolean didShowListingDialog = false;
```

...which you check and set to true inside the showListingDialog like so:

```
private void showListingDialog() {
    if (!didshowListingDialog) {
        didshowListingDialog = true;
        // show the dialog here
    }
}
```

If you ever want the dialog to show again, you can set the flag back to false.